# How to set date to default time zone

Tags: extjs, timezone

I would like to set date to default time zone. At this moment my date looks like this: 2013-04-08T22:00:00 +02:00. I need to set my date to +00:00.

I tried to get the offset of my date and I received -120. Is it possible to set time offset? Are there maybe any better solutions?

Anybody an idea?

I'm using EXT JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript's Date object is bound to the time zone of the computer itself.  There is no way to change the zone offset programmatically to an arbitrary value.

There is some work going on to add this functionality to the [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library, but it is [still in progress](https://github.com/timrwood/moment/issues/611).

If you are just looking to get the time at UTC in ISO format, you can use `.toISOString()`

If you are speaking about code that is specific to the [Ext.Date object](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Date) from ExtJS, please edit your question and post some sample code so we can get a better idea of what you are talking about.  Thanks.

Comment: I used .toUTCString function and it works :). Thank you for your answer.